# WPF: Detect Datagrid changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a datagrid

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

It's source

```
    /*** Added constructor ***/
    public SetupVM()
    {
        ConnectionString = Path.Combine(DATABASE_PATH, DATABASE_NAME);
        MyList = new List<MyObjectINotifyImplemented>();

        /* MyList= new ObservableCollection<MyObjectINotifyImplemented>(); */

        if (!File.Exists(ConnectionString))
        {
            FirstRun();
        }
    }

    public void FirstRun()
    {
        BoilerPlate boilerPlate = new BoilerPlate();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(DATABASE_PATH + "\\databaseFile");

        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.CreateTable<MyObjectINotifyImplemented>();

            foreach (seed in MyObjectINotifyImplemented.seeds)
            {
                var t = conn.Insert(seed);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<MyObjectINotifyImplemented> _mylist;

    public List<MyObjectINotifyImplemented> MyList
    {
        get { return _mylist; }
        set
        {
            _mylist= value;
            /****  Called on initialization in ctor and never again ****/
            MyMethodThatShouldBeCalled();
        }
    }
```

Sample of the model:

```
class MyObjectINotifyImplemented : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  private string _name;

  public string Name
  {
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
      _name = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
  }

  /** Generated by VS **/
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

I see this question asked over and over again, but I'm implementing everything that I can find?

Most questions are resolved by binding mode or adding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.

What could be missing?  Ignore typos, I just cut out the relevant bits by hand.

Comment: What exactly is the problem, it sounds like you have a data change you are not seeing? Or the binding is not showing at all?

Comment: MyMethodThatShouldBeCalled(); is never called.

Comment: Where do you attempt to assign the list?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand?

Comment: You have to make an assignment like `MyList = new <MyObjectINotifyImplemented>() { new MyObjectINotifyImplemented() }` somewhere. Until that assignments happens, the call to `MyMethodThatShouldBeCalled` won't be called. There has to be an assignment somewhere otherwise the reference to `MyList` will remain null.

Comment: Oh sorry, It's in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Most questions are resolved by binding mode or adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

It only makes sense to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` and `Mode` properties when the control actually may actually set the source property. A `DataGrid` does *not* set the source of the `ItemsSource` property so setting these properties are pointless in this context.

The `DataGrid` will never call the setter of your `MyList` source property. Only the getter will be called. This is the expected behaviour. You should define the binding like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
```

If you for example bind the `Text` property of a `TextBox`, it does makes sense to specify an `UpdateSourceTrigger` and a `Mode` to control when and if the `TextBox` sets the source property. But it doesn't when binding the `ItemsSource` property of an `ItemsControl`.

It's unclear why you expect or want the setter of the source collection property to get called by the framework here because it's not supposed to. And it won't.

If you want to detect items being added or removed from the `DataGrid`, you should replace the `List<MyObjectINotifyImplemented>` with an `ObservableCollection<MyObjectINotifyImplemented>` and handle the `CollectionChanged` event of the source collection. The collection itself won't be replaced.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, DataGrid's are not supporting two-way binding?  Because I find hundreds of questions on Stack Overflow asking to set this up, most of which have a successful outcome.  I also don't see anything like this on Microsoft docs, where would one look?



The List<> or Observable collection is sourced from a SQLite DB.  What I would like to do is write to the DB when one of the rows is updated, which is what MyMethodThatShouldBeCalled() is supposed to handle.



I will look into the CollectionChanged event, cheers.

Comment: @ArchieMoses: When a property of an object that is represented by a row is updated, the setter of this property is called. That would be the `Name` property in your example. But the source collection property is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

Change the definition of `MyList` from `List<MyObjectINotifyImplemented>` to `ObservableCollection<MyObjectINotifyImplemented>` which is what you are newing up in the constructor.

Comment: Argh, typo.  I tried both, this was a C&P mistake from the latest attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to sound negative on your issue, but it should only be called once.  That is the only place where you are actually loading the list.  Unless there is something else on the form that will force some refresh and requery your data such as from your connection string / database, it wont.  All you have is

1. Prepare an empty list (that should be ObservableCollection)
2. Define your data grid (but still nothing indicating the forms DataContext is actually set)
3. Your no file based on your connectionString setting, you call FirstRun, but don't show what FirstRun does.
4. If the file expected DOES exist, it does not show you querying anything TO populate it.

You have provided a variety of partial implementations, but obviously not enough to get the rest of the functionality across.

Comment: No need for sorry, thanks for reading.  I've added the code, it is just seeding with default data.  Binding back to front works just fine, it's the other way that is not working.